# How to dispatch an event with dynamic content in Flex?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I often have the requirement to dispatch a `flash.events.Event` with soem custom `String` text, like:

```
protected function mouseClicked(event:Event) {
     //here I'd want to notify anyone interested in the button click,
     //and also transfer the name of the button (or whatever) that was clicked - assume some dynamic value
     dispatchEvent(new Event("myMouseEvent"), button.name));
}
```

Of course the above event is invalid. But is there any event that can be used for that type of events? Maybe the `TextEvent`, but I don't know if I'd be misusing it here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [AS3 Custom DialogBox: How to send pushed Buttons label to Main.fla](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30393509/as3-custom-dialogbox-how-to-send-pushed-buttons-label-to-main-fla)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To include additional data with your events, create a custom event class by extending `Event` (or any sub-class of `Event`) and adding your own properties. For example:

```
class NameEvent extends Event {
    public static const NAME_CLICK:String = "nameClick";
    public var name:String;
    public function NameEvent(type:String, name:String) {
        this.name = name;
        super(type);
    }
}

dispatchEvent(new NameEvent(NameEvent.NAME_CLICK, button.name));
```

Note that your event type strings ("nameClick" in this example) should be globally unique, otherwise listeners could get them confused with other event types. For example "click" is already expected to be a `MouseEvent`. I often add prefixes to my custom event types, for example "NameEvent::click".

---

Another option that does not require creating a custom event is to rely on the expected target to get additional data. For example:

```
// dispatch a custom event from a Button
dispatchEvent(new Event("myClick"));

// handler for "myClick" events on the button
function myClicked(e:Event):void {
    var button:Button = e.target as Button;
    trace(button.name);
}
```

This is not as flexible and also more fragile than using a custom event class, but sometimes a quick easy solution.

Comment: For DisplayObject you need to override the clone() method.

Comment: @BotMaster No you don't, you only need to override `clone()` if the event will be re-dispatched (in order for it to be re-dispatched as the custom event). It's a good practice but not usually necessary.

Comment: From the docs: "When creating your own custom Event class, you must override the inherited Event.clone() method in order for it to duplicate the properties of your custom class. If you do not set all the properties that you add in your event subclass, those properties will not have the correct values when listeners handle the redispatched event." That's why DisplayObject need this in multi layer displaylist as the custom event traverses it. What you say is correct for non DisplayObject.

Comment: Nope, it has nothing to do with display objects. It has to do with re-dispatching an event, as the docs say. Bubbling does not count as re-dispatching. Using `dispatchEvent()` on an already dispatching event is where `clone()` gets called.

Comment: @Aaron you don't *have* to, but it is recommended to override the clone() method.

Comment: @null No one was recommending not to override `clone()`. ;)