# AS3: How to dispatch function from class to mainframe

Tags: actionscript-3, class, flash, events, timeline

This might be a silly question. But how can I call a function (to execute) from a class to the timeline.

For example, I have the class "Test" and I want to execute the function "Next" on the timline (which it is only a function to show next slide).

Hope you understand what I'm trying to do.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice for communication (in this scenario!) is to use `Event`s.

1. The timeline create the object of your class `Test` and registers an
   event listener.
2. The object of your class `Test` dispatch an `Event`.
3. The function that the timeline registered for that `Event` will be executed.

[Please take a look at this question that wants to send additional information to the main timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30393509/as3-custom-dialogbox-how-to-send-pushed-buttons-label-to-main-fla). In your case, you do not need a custom `Event`, because you do not want to send any information along. You only want to communicate the occurrence of the event. You can put that information into the type of the event. an example for a dispatch could look like this:

```
dispatchEvent(new Event("next"));
```

Creating a custom class allows you to put that `String` literal that describes the type into a constant, which prevents errors caused by accidentally misspelling the type. That might be a reason to create a custom `Event` class anyway, even only for the sake of a place to put those constants.

```
dispatchEvent(new PresentationEvent(PresentationEvent.NEXT));
```

Again, this would do the same as the previous line. this is also covered in the other question and the answer to it. Please take a look.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Could you provide me the code I should put on the timeline and the class? It's driving me crazy! thank you again!

Comment: @JoshChisnerman I'm afraid I cannot do that. SO is not the place to ask other people to write code for you. If you have specific questions how to implement my answer, go ahead and ask them. I'd be happy to elaborate. Teaching people how to fish instead of giving them fish, that kind of jazz.